# Displaying shorten goo.gl urls statistics on goo.gl panel

Tags: url, google-api, goo.gl

I'm shortening my "news" page's long URLs by using this code.

```
  var api_key = 'AIzaSyCNGB0ddmvRkn5h************';
    var docURL = document.URL;
    function makeRequest() {
      var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
        'resource': {'longUrl': docURL}
      });
      request.execute(function(response) {
          var newItem = {
              url : response.id  
          }
        $(".googlURL").html($("#shareButtons").tmpl({url : response.id , title : $('.newsDetail h3').text()));
      });
    }

    function load() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey(api_key);
      gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1', makeRequest);
    }
```

this code creates goo.gl URL perfectly.

When someone visit the news details, it creates a shorten url automatically even any url is not created before.

But i would like to see the URLs in my goo.gl panel.

When i visit http://goo.gl/ with my account, i can not see how many URLs created and how many times they visited.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: is there anybody to help me about this question? :)

Comment: i still need an answer :(

Comment: i'm looking for same solutions, have you find one since 2 years ?

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution as below about your question. May be that can help you

> If you have already created a shortened goo.gl url just type .info at
>   the end (e.g. goo.gl/url.info)